# Time of curdate()?

Tags: mysql

I have made a surprising observation - can anybody explain this?

```
mysql> explain select * from game_instance where start_datetime between STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY), ' ', '00:00:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') and STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), ' ', '23:59:59'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys                | key                          | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | game_instance | range | game_instance_start_datetime | game_instance_start_datetime | 4       | NULL | 1707666 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Contrasted with:

```
mysql> explain select * from game_instance where start_datetime between DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) and DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys                | key                          | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | game_instance | range | game_instance_start_datetime | game_instance_start_datetime | 4       | NULL | 812538 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I look at the output of the two expressions used in the WHERE, I do see a difference, but I thought they would essentially the same:

```
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY), ' ', '00:00:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') d1,DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) d2;
+---------------------+------------+
| d1                  | d2         |
+---------------------+------------+
| 2019-08-28 00:00:00 | 2019-08-28 |
+---------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Clearly there is a significant difference, but by a factor of 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First query will effectively be:

```
BETWEEN 2019-08-28 00:00:00 AND 2019-08-29 23:59:59
```

And, second query will be:

```
BETWEEN 2019-08-28 AND 2019-08-29
```

`start_datetime` is a field of **datetime** type.

So, in the second query, MySQL will typecast the constant date literals `2019-08-28` and `2019-08-29` to datetime literals, `2019-08-28 00:00:00` and `2019-08-29 00:00:00` (start of 29 Aug 2019), respectively, for comparison.

You can clearly see that the second query will be effectively ignoring the data from full day (24-hour period) on `2019-08-29`. Thus there is a difference in number of rows either of these two queries would analyze.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n in those cases i wished MySQL 's `EXPLAIN` would show these implicit datatype casts in the extra column off the explain output something like "implicit cast from date to datetime needed" then you see directly what the problem is .. Not wierd in a loosed typed RDMS right?

Comment: @RaymondNijland true. I have found that even `Explain Extended..` lacks a bit of basic details from a intermediate-level MySQL user's perspective.

Comment: Note sure what you mean or what you are going at..  Keep in mind there is `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON`  which (could) include much more information depending which MySQL version you are running... Also keep in mind there is a option to [trace the optimizer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-tracing.html)